# "Hit dropped by filter" for view with User-ID reports enabled

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to enable tracking users using the `userId` property in Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager.

So far I am:

- Setting `userId` in the `dataLayer` when a user logs in
- Sending this variable to Google Analytics in my Google Tag Manager tag

And I have created a view in Google Analytics which has User-ID tracking enabled. Unfortunately, this view isn't registering any events.

Using the "tag explorer" extension, I can see the following when a user is logged in:

```
Web Property ID: UA-XXXXXXX-X
Code Version/Syntax Universal
Implemented in Google Tag Manager GTM-XXXXXX
Protocol version number 1
User ID 765465654654654787
```

However, in the output from using the "record" function shows:

```
Hit 1: Session Start
Pageview - Home

Username: 765465654654654787

View: User Tracking 2
  Mutations
    Hit dropped by filter
```

So these page views are not being included in the view with User-ID reports enabled. Why might this be? It looks like the `userId` is being properly set as it appears in the Tag Explorer extension.

Comment: I know but that can be a little obvius, are you using filters? 
The tag assistant take in consideration almost all the configuration and it's quite accurate. So i think that you option in the first place is remove all your filters of the desired property (also check that are you selecting the correct )

Comment: I'm not using any filters I'm afraid. Thanks for the suggestion anyway :-)

Comment: Haha, sorry but i've to ask first :). My last quick option is check if all the tags (i see that you are using GTM), includes the user id. You need to add on all the hits the field of the user ID not only on the page view . (this is diferent if you're using the hardcode GA snippet)